# How to run Jmeter Script in bitbucket Pipeline

Tags: jmeter, bitbucket-pipelines

Im quite new to bitbucket pipeline and i was looking into how to run my jmeter script in the pipeline without using Jenkins or bamboo. I have created a bitbucket-pipelines.yml file and got an issue "jmeter: command not found"
here is the script that i created.

```
pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          name: Jmeter
          script:
           - jmeter run Observability_Test.jmx
```

Answer (score 0):

If `jmeter` command is not found you need to [install JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-get-started-jmeter-installation-test-plans/) prior to trying to launch the test.

Example configuration:

```
   pipelines:
      default:
       - step:
          script: 
           - apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y openjdk-11-jre wget
           - cd /opt && wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-5.4.3.tgz && tar xf apache-jmeter-5.4.3.tgz
           - cd apache-jmeter-5.4.3/bin && ./jmeter -n -t /path/to/Observability_Test.jmx
           - cd apache-jmeter-5.4.3/bin && ./jmeter -n -t /path/to/Observability_Test.jmx
```

More information: [Tips for scripting tasks with Bitbucket Pipelines](https://www.atlassian.com/continuous-delivery/tutorials/bitbucket-pipelines)

Comment: Hi, How do I know the JMX file path in Bitbucket server if I have added .jmx in root? thanks for your help!